# org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We are getting:

> org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException

frequently on this code:

```
if(claimBasicInfo.getsFacilityName()==null) {
    claimBasicInfo.setsFacilityName("");
}

try {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(claimBasicInfo);
    getHibernateTemplate().flush(); 
    getHibernateTemplate().evict(claimBasicInfo);
}
```

We found that that this lock exception occurs while executing `getHibernateTemplate().flush();` Is this a good practice to call flush immediately after `saveOrUpdate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a good practice to do things blindly without understanding what they actually mean.

Calling `flush()` just persists the changes from the persistence context to the database. Sometimes you may need to call it yourself (when for example there's database logic that changes the data), but usually you let the transaction boundaries handle the flushing.

If you remove `flush()` from the code in the question, you'll get the exception at the end of the transaction (where flushing implicitly happens). The exception happens when the database is actually accessed (as that's when the locks become a real issue), calling `saveOrUpdate` just "prepares" that object to be saved.